# Assign keys (keymap) to Transformation Orientation?

Tags: python, shortcut

I could not find anyone asking this question, which means there are probably already quick keyboard commands to do this.

What I want to do is assign keyboard shortcuts to transformation orientations. Especially Local, Global, and View. But preferably others as well. For example, I may set up something such as Shift + 1 for local, Shift + 2 for view, and Shift + 3 for global. However, when I try to assign shortcuts to these using the right click context menu, the commands just show up as "Context Enum Menu", with a command of wm.context_menu_enum and context attribute of scene.type. I'm pretty sure this is not correct (it throws an error when the command is pressed).

Does anyone know how to pull this off? All I can find is the pie menu shortcut (,). That's better than nothing, but I would like to have direct commands.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can only think of Quick Favorites, or a python script. I don't typically use scripts, so I don't have one. :|

Comment: It doesn't seem to let you add it to quick favorites either. Although the orientation menu (key = ,) is good enough for a two step command if I can't have a single step.